# direct way to launch activity on wearable from notification action button?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, wear-os

I would like to know, if it is possible to launch an activity on the wearable from an wearable notification action button. The default usage is that a notification action on the wearable launches the intent on the handheld. I know that i can build a workaround: catch the intent on the handheld and send a message to the wearable. But isn't there a direct way?

Answer: It is not possible at the moment, see the comments under the marked "answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to (easily) launch an activity on the wearable based on a notification generated on the phone.

However, you can do it with a bit of extra code. The solution is to run code on the phone when the action is selected on the notification. This code on the phone will use the Data Layer API to send a message or set a data item that the wearable is waiting for. When the wearable sees this incoming update, it will start the Activity on the wearable.

There is a sample that shows how to do this here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SynchronizedNotifications

Comment: but one still need a separate wearable application for it, am I wrong ?

Comment: yes, you need to maintain an application on the wearable side to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is. You can use  `PendingIntent.getActivity`, to get a handler for your Activity, and the on the wearable extender, you can do:

```
NotificationCompat.WearableExtender extender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();
extender.setCustomSizePreset(Notification.WearableExtender.SIZE_FULL_SCREEN);
extender.setDisplayIntent(pedingIntent);
```

this will call your Activity on the wearable,

Comment: Unfortunately my notification is created on the handheld. "You can only create and issue custom notifications on the wearable, and the system does not sync these notifications to the handheld."

Comment: I thought you had a wearable app, isn't it the case?

Comment: i do, but i want the app on the handheld to create a notification with an action button to start the google maps navigation. However, with the wearable extender it's only possible to launch activities on the handheld and not directly on the wearable.

Comment: No you can't. You need to handle the notifications on both sides. To keen the notification local use `setLocalOnly`